# How to highlight a page in the page list (Admin Menu)?

Tags: plugin-development

Ok bear with me, I could not find any info on this online. I'm creating a plugin and I need to highlight one of the pages It will create upon activation.

WordPress currently does this here;
[image: Highlighted Home Page as Front Page in WordPress]

How is this achieved? If anyone has any reading material they know of or if it's a simple thing to do I'd love to know.

> Clarification: I'm not looking to highlight the row, but add the text
> next to the page link. E.g. `my page - Your Page`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a stylesheet for admin using the following code,

add this in function.php

```
function mmk_enqueue_custom_admin_style() {
            wp_register_style( 'pixel_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin.css', false, '1.0.0' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'pixel_admin_css' );
        }
 

   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mmk_enqueue_custom_admin_style' );
```

then add create admin.css in theme directory:
you can using following class to highlight

```
.row-title
```